# Matlab: Appending data from .mat files to specified ranges in excel sheets

Tags: excel, matlab, append

I have a bunch of .mat files in matlab which have been saved as A1.mat, A2.mat, A3.mat etc. The .mat files are matrices containing numbers. 
I’m trying to append the data from each .mat file to already existing excel files  (A1.xlsx, A2.xls, A3.xls) where the .mat data should be placed in a certain range in the excel sheet. 
I need the .mat data to be placed in the range B2:F10 as I have predefined headers in the first row A1:F1 and first column A1:A10.
I also have some predefined equations in the excel sheets in column G2:G10 where I want to do some calculation on the added .mat data.

I have .mat data up until A60 (and thus excel files up until A60.xls) so was hoping this could be done in a loop.

I’ve tried  dlmwrite ‘-append’ but it won’t let me specify the excel range nor keep the predefined formulas in the excel sheets.

Does anybody have a clue on how to do this?

All help greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `dlmwrite()` you can use either `csvwrite()` or `writetable()` or `xlswrite()`.
However, you should pay attention to the following:

- `csvwrite()` works only with .csv files, so you should covert .xls to .csv (this can be done using Excel itself)
- with `writetable()` you must convert your matrix in a table (a combination of `mat2cell()` and then `cell2table()`)

All of them allow you, anyway, to specify a row/column offset to write your data:

- in `csvwrite()` such offsets can be specified using the 3rd and 4th input argument
- in `writetable()` you must specify the `Range` Name/Value
- in `xlswrite()` a third input argument is a string in which you can specify the excel cells range you want to write on (e.g. `'A1:A10'`)

More infos can be found at their respective help page:
help for writetable [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)
help for csvwrite [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)
help for xlswrite [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)

Comment: I've actually tried that, but I could not figure out how I can both append new data while keeping data and formulas already specified in the .csv file in addition to specifying that I want the appended data to be in the range B2:F10?  Could you possibly write that as an example? Thansk a lot.

Comment: In addition I have matlab version 2011 so I don't have the writetable() built-in function, unfortunately.... But I'm able to use the csvwrite but Im not able to 'append' the data to the stuff I already have in the .csv file. Do you know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I've edited my question with another suggestion, that is `xlswrite()`. In `xlswrite()` you can specify a third input argument that is the cell range. So you can easily write your matrix in range B2:F10 by calling `xlswrite()` as follows: `xlswrite('myFile.xlsx',myMatrix,'B2:F10')`

Comment: So far as I can tell, both `csvwrite` and `xlswrite` are *not* capable of true appending: you have to know a priori what the last current row in use is.  This is bad (on MathWork's part)